# How can i terminate my application in iPhone depends on time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Iam displaying time in my application using NSTimer Class starting with 00:00.00 (mm:ss.SS) when my application launched. I want to terminate my application when time reaches to 75:00.00 (mm:ss.SS) in iPhone.

Comment: I did not understand if you want to stop the timer or application launches in the second case the statement "exit(0);"

Comment: The chance is high, apple will reject your app because it doesn't meet apple's rules. And I think i should appreciate that apple rejects such apps because apple wont accept the app which quit with exit (0)

Comment: actually it is not recommended (although I have submitted with this application) look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you start the timer,immediately next line call the below method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:75.0];
```

And stopTimer method should be like this:

```
-(void) stopTimer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet will do the work for you. But its not recommended to use the exit() method to quit the app as it will appear that the app has been crashed to the end user. I recommend you to show an alert after 75 mins and ask the user to quit the app.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:270000
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(quitTheApp)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

- (void)quitTheApp
{
    exit(0);
}
```